# Best way to convert JSON data to an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I am currently using `eval` in JavaScript to convert JSON data returned from the server into an object.

```
eval ("myObject="+data);
```

I've been told that `eval` is 'evil' and can open up big security problems.

I'm wondering - is using `eval` to convert JSON data to an object the accepted practice?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Now I'm curious if `JSON.parse` wasn't a thing back then..

Answer (score 1):

The reason eval is considered a bad practice is that user can evaluate anything that is sent from the server. This means if you have comments forum and the user submits some JavaScript code for the comments and you eval on the client side then your website can easily be hijacked.

I like the JQuery-Json plug-in. You can check it out using the following link:

[link text](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

Comment: Even John Resig suggests that you use the json2.js library. It's also baked into jquery 1.4.2 as jQuery.parseJSON - if that's the only function you need (rather than parse _and_ stringify). I'd say that jquery-json doesn't really have a place here anymore. Also, we can't assume jQuery on a non jQuery tagged question

Comment: If Job Resig suggests to use json2.js then I am moving to json2.js from right now. Thanks!